# LNK2019 - Unresolved External - C++ & MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2010, linker-errors, unresolved-external

I have downloaded & installed [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com) **- the [full version](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/5.6.html) -,** included all headers correctly (VC++ Directories), copied the .dll in System32 and gave the linker the library directory & library.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "my_global.h"
#include "mysql.h"
#include <iostream>

int _tmain (int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MYSQL *my;
    my = mysql_init (NULL);
    if (!my)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if (!mysql_real_connect (my, "localhost", "root", "Test", "testing", 3307, NULL, 0))
        //Print error...
    mysql_close (my);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Even though everything should work, it still throws me linker errors...

```
1>MYSQL_Connection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_close@4 referenced in function _wmain
1>MYSQL_Connection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_errno@4 referenced in function _wmain
1>MYSQL_Connection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_error@4 referenced in function _wmain
1>MYSQL_Connection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_real_connect@32 referenced in function _wmain
1>MYSQL_Connection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_init@4 referenced in function _wmain
1>C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\C++_SQL_Testing\Debug\MYSQL_Connection.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
```

I have came across different "solutions" in the internet and tried them without success. Someone also mentioned a problem with 32 and 64 bit. This should not even exist for me, as MySQL states this on their website:

`Note: MySQL Installer is 32 bit, but will install both 32 bit and 64 bit binaries.`

**Does anyone know what could be wrong ?**